# How should I calculate task value in hours?

Tags: entry-level, planning

I got new job and boss told that I should estimate value of the task, that he's giving, in hours, because salary is per hour, but I do not have idea how should I do that? Is there some formula or algorithm?

Comment: Yes, I'm Employee.

Comment: It's a guess at this point. As you get involved with the tasks especially on a particular project, your guesses will get better.

Answer (score 2):

> I got new job and boss told that I should estimate value of the task, that he's giving, in hours

I'm understanding that as your boss wants to know how long the task will take you to complete in hours. I assume he knows what your hourly salary is or will be passing along your estimated number of hours to somebody else who does. That person can then work out how much it's going to cost them to pay you for the time spent on the task, and therefore how much they'd have to charge a client for that work.

For you, there's no algorithm or formula you can use. Estimating how long a task will take is simply a skill you'll have to develop. Look at similar tasks you've completed in the past and how long they took, and use that as a basis for your estimate.

For example, if you've been asked to code a registration form for a website, and you've built a registration form before and it took you about 40 hours, you might estimate that this new one will take you 40 hours as well. However, if the original one took 40 hours because you had to learn a lot of new skills that you don't need to learn this time, then you might lower the estimate to 20 or 30 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Simply say to yourself I want to be paid x amount an hour and I'm going to work y hours this week. Simply multiply x by y. Then the product of those two numbers is you estimated cost. Hope that this helps you.

Comment: Well, that's not exactly what I'm looking for, but at least something.

Comment: Don't factor in your rate. Your fully burdened rate is much higher than what you see on your paycheck. They only want to see the number of hours.